# External chrome extension can not enable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I install chrome extension using `registry key` in window and its working good when I start chrome it automatically install that extension. And that it is disable by default but problem is that when I try to enable it from `chrome://extensions` its not working the box is checked but it couldn't enable like it not show the icon in omni bar.
At the bottom of **enable** button this is written **Not From Chrome Store**.

I try to install this extension by drop and drag system it install successfully and enable by default but if I disable it and try to enable it does not work.

What is the problem ?

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in the installation. There are possible reasons this is happening as listed in
[common mistakes when installing with the registry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry):

> -Not specifying the same id/version as the one listed in the Chrome Web Store
>
> -Key created in the wrong location in the registry
>
> -Registry entry points to the wrong path to the .crx file in the Chrome Web Store
>
> -Permissions problems on a network share